# Why doesn't `.innerText` property work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, find

The following code does not work in Firefox

```
var selectedCategories = $("#category_filter .checkbox-input-group .checked").find("span");
for (var i = 0; i < selectedCategories.length; i++) {
    categories.push(selectedCategories[i].innerText);
}
```

Please tell me how I can get a similar result

Comment: please add code in jsfiddle

Comment: Better way to iterate over all selected elements is `$('#your-selector').each(function () { //code here  });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerText` is a non-standard property and Firefox doesn't support it, you should use `textContent` instead. However, it should be noted that IE8 and below do not support the `textContent` property.

I would suggest using jQuery `.eq()` and `.text()` methods:

```
categories.push(selectedCategories.eq(i).text());
```

Also note that for creating arrays you can also use the jQuery `.map()` method:

```
var arr = selectedCategories.map(function() {
     return $(this).text();
     // Alternatively:
     // return (this.innerText || this.textContent);
}).get();
```

Comment: @PavelIvanov You are vey welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var selectedCategories = $("#category_filter .checkbox-input-group .checked").find("span").length;
 var categories = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedCategories; i++) {
        categories.push(selectedCategories[i].innerText);
}
```